# is there a way to make multiple execute of pdo query php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my function ;and its not woring, the message error is ,exception

```
PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
```

this is my function

```
public function admin_insert_lien_footer( $foo_title_all, $foo_title, $foo_url1, $foo_url2 ) {
    try {

    $url = $foo_url1.", ".$foo_url2;
    $mydata = explode(", ", $url);

    #   mysql connection
    parent::dbConnect();
    #   sql statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `t_footer_lien` VALUES( ?, ?, ? )";
    #   data prepare
    $data = $this->PDO->prepare( $sql );
    #   execute my statment
    $execute = $data->execute( 
        array( '', $foo_title_all, $foo_title ) 
    );

    #   sql statement
    $sql_join = "INSERT INTO `t_footer_lien_join` VALUES( :a, :b, :c )";
    #   data prepare
    $data_join = $this->PDO->prepare( $sql_join );

    for ($i=0; $i <= 1; $i++) { 
    #   ----
    $data_join->bindParam( ':a', $a );  
    $data_join->bindParam( ':b', $b );  
    $data_join->bindParam( ':c', $c );  



    $a = $this->PDO->lastInsertId();
    $b = $mydata[$i];
    $c = 'selected';
    #   execute my statment
    $execute_join = $data_join->execute();

    }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

and thanks for help

Comment: Can you `DESCRIBE t_footer_lien_join`? (Type that into your MySQL)

Comment: t_footer_lien_join(foo_id, foo_url_ foo_selected)
t_footer_lien(foo_id, foo_title_all, foo_title)

Comment: I'm trying to determine what the constraints are on your table. If you're inserting duplicate data on a UNIQUE column, then you'll get errors like the one above.